# Trying to mock a method to add Store code to database in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am new to mocking and I have basic understanding of OOP concepts.
There is a method in interface to add a Sub Store code to the database.
This method implementation is in another class file that I want to mock. following is the method.

```
public SubStore AddSubStoreCode(SubStore subStoreCode)
        {
            db.SubStores.Add(subStoreCode);
            SaveStoreCodes();
            return subStoreCode;
        }
```

In the test class file, I have setup the mock object and the method to act upon. I am not sure how to proceed with the act and assert part to complete the Moq unit test. following is the snippet

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void ShouldBeAbleToAddSubStoreCode()
        {
            //Arrange
            var mockStoreCodeService = new Mock<IStoreCodeService>();

            mockStoreCodeService.Setup(s => s.AddSubStoreCode(It.IsAny<SubStore>));


        }
```

Please advise

Comment: did u debug the code to see it it's being stored ?

Comment: Yes, its storing into the database. The StoreCode calls the SaveStoreCodes method which sves to the database.

Comment: how should i proceed with the act and assert part to complete the unit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IStoreCodeService` with `AddSubStoreCode` is a **dependency** of a component you are testing. Your test is missing the most important part - system under test (so far, you have only instantiated and set up dependency).

```
[TestMethod]
public void SomeMethod_ShouldAddSubStoreCode_ThroughService()
{
    // Arrange:
    // - create dependency and create instance of system under test (sut)
    // - we don't need mock.Setup here; verification is made at the end
    var mockStoreCodeService = new Mock<IStoreCodeService>();
    var sut = new SomeComponent(mockStoreCodeService);

    // Act: execute method on sut
    sut.SomeMethod();

    // Assert: verify expectations (that call has been made to service)
    mockStoreCodeService.Verify(m => m.AddSubStoreCode(It.IsAny<SubStore>));
}
```

We skipped `mock.Setup` as it is not needed in such test (where we verify whether our component communicates with other components; as is the case here).

Comment: Thanks. Will try this as well. Just another help; where did you learn about mocking?

Comment: @khan88: various sources: [Art of Unit Testing](http://artofunittesting.com), Martin Fowler online articles (on testing), this site :-) as well as frameworks wiki pages. **Moq** and **FakeItEasy** have excellent documentations explaining how to do most common stuff. I also run a [blog series](http://jimmykeen.net/articles/09-jul-2012/mocking-frameworks-comparison-part-1-introduction) where I compare different mocking frameworks, you might find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link. It has a very useful explanation of mocking. It may help you:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30381/Introduction-to-Mocking

First you should setup you mock repository

```
private MockRepository _mocks;

[SetUp]
    public void initialize()
    {
        _mocks = new MockRepository();            
    }
```

then to set the expectation u should do this :

```
using (_mocks.Record())
{
    SetupResult.For(averageJoeService.Authenticate(null,
        null)).IgnoreArguments().Return(true); 

}
```

where `Authenticate` is the function that you want to moke it in your case it's `AddSubStoreCode`

after the expectation

```
The next part is the Playback which is the code that will trigger the expectations and produce the desired result. Here is the Playback part:
 using (_mocks.Playback())
{
    Assert.AreEqual(100,_accountBalanceService.GetAccountBalanceByUser(user)); 
}
```

GetAccountBalanceByUser is the second function that you want to use to complete your test.

Comment: Thanks for your input Sora. I will check with these and get back.

Comment: if you find my answer useful please make sure to accept it as the correct answer

Comment: I had another concern. Here the Rhyno mock is Used. I am using MoQ framework, so how do i go about with this framework?